# Reset table preferences with angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have the following table in my application where user can set their notification preferences.

1. when the page loads the $ctrl.getNotificationSettings() will be invoked and it will list the users notification preferences for various categories.please refer screenshot
2. I have also written a $ctrl.save() which allows the user to update their preferences and save it which works fine.
3. Now i have a reset button with $ctrl.cancelSettings().here i want the user to be able to  change few preferences and if he decides to revert it before saving it the table should be set with the preferences how it was when loaded. Need some help on this part.

i cannot use forms here because of some other challenges.

**HTML**

```
  <tbody>
  <tr data-ng-repeat="app in $ctrl.notificationSettings" class="content-box">
        <td data-ng-bind="app.appName"></td>
        <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.email" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
        <td><ng-checkbox data-checked="app.sms" rounded="true"></ng-checkbox></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="content-box">
        <button class="ng-button-primary" data-ng-click="$ctrl.saveSettings()">Save</button>
        <button class="ng-button-secondary" data-ng-click="$ctrl.cancelSettings()">Reset</button>
  </div>
```

**JS**

```
            $ctrl.getNotificationSettings = function () { 
                var url = "http://localhost:3000/json/notification-settings.json";
                rsicontext.getData(url).then(function (response) {
                    $ctrl.notificationSettings = response.data;
                    $ctrl.appName = response.data.appName;
                    $ctrl.emailNotification = response.data.email;
                    $ctrl.smsNotification = response.data.sms;
                });
            };


            $ctrl.cancelSettings = function () {
                console.log("cancel settings");
            };
```

**JSON format to list the data**

```
    [{
    "appName":"Finance",
    "email":true,
    "sms":false
    },
    {
    "appName":"Sports",
    "email":true,
    "sms":true
    },
    {
    "appName":"Economics",
    "email":false,
    "sms":false
    },
    {
    "appName":"Health",
    "email":false,
    "sms":true
    }]
```

[image]

Comment: where do you want to use forms?

Answer (score 0):

what about the use of angular.copy to make a deep copy of the original object?

```
  $ctrl.getNotificationSettings = function () { 
            var url = "http://localhost:3000/json/notification-settings.json";
            rsicontext.getData(url).then(function (response) {
                $ctrl.notificationSettings = response.data;
                $ctrl.appName = response.data.appName;
                $ctrl.emailNotification = response.data.email;
                $ctrl.smsNotification = response.data.sms;
                $scope.origData = angular.copy(response.data);
            });
        };

        $ctrl.cancelSettings = function () {
            $ctrl.notificationSettings = $scope.origData;
                $ctrl.appName = $scope.origData.appName;
                $ctrl.emailNotification = $scope.origData.email;
                $ctrl.smsNotification = $scope.origData.sms;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's 2 ways to solve your problem:

After retrieving data store it in temporary placeholder, and if user executes $ctrl.cancelSettings set form data to that of placeholder.eg:

```
    $ctrl.getNotificationSettings = function () { 
        var url = "http://localhost:3000/json/notification-settings.json";
        rsicontext.getData(url).then(function (response) {
            $ctrl.placeholder = {};

            $ctrl.notificationSettings = response.data;
            $ctrl.placeholder.notificationSettings = response.data;

            $ctrl.appName = response.data.appName;
            $ctrl.placeholder.appName = response.data.appName;

            $ctrl.emailNotification = response.data.email;
            $ctrl.placeholder.emailNotification = response.data.email;

            $ctrl.smsNotification = response.data.sms;
            $ctrl.placeholder.smsNotification = response.data.sms;
        });
    };
    $ctrl.cancelSettings = function () {
        $ctrl.notificationSettings = $ctrl.placeholder.notificationSettings;
        $ctrl.appName = $ctrl.placeholder.appName;
        $ctrl.emailNotification = $ctrl.placeholder.emailNotification;
        $ctrl.smsNotification = $ctrl.placeholder.smsNotification;
    };
```

Or another solution would be just repeat the first function call in cancel operation:

```
    $ctrl.cancelSettings = function () {
        var url = "http://localhost:3000/json/notification-settings.json";
        rsicontext.getData(url).then(function (response) {
            $ctrl.notificationSettings = response.data;
            $ctrl.appName = response.data.appName;
            $ctrl.emailNotification = response.data.email;
            $ctrl.smsNotification = response.data.sms;
        });
    };
```